# Link Wordpress website to a different Google Analytics Account

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I am maintaining a Wordpress website, and use Google Analytics to track visits.

The problem is that to do this I have linked the site with my personal Google account. Now I am going to hand over to a new webmaster. I don't want to hand over the details of my Google account, so it will have to be set up with a different Google account. I can find previous answers that tell me how to set up Google Analytics with Wordpress from scratch, but not to change to a different account.

Can anyone suggest what might be the best way forward?

Comment: Go to the admin section of the Google analytics account and add this new persons email address with full rights.  They can then remove you if they wish.

Comment: That sounds really helpful, many thanks.